# Почему не работают условия из virtual метода в override методе

Tags: c#, unity3d, virtual, override

Всем доброго времени суток! Объясните пожалуйста, почему класс наследник переопределяет метод и выполняет весь функционал, за исключением условий?
У меня есть главный базовый класс "Skill" с `protected virtual void Use() {}`
Этот класс наследует другой базовый класс "PlayerSkill", который содержит функционал обозначенный ниже. Так вот, когда я наследую любым другим классом класс "PlayerSkill", то у меня в переопределенном методе выполняется весь функционал из Skill и PlayerSkill, но почему-то в открытую игнорируются условия прописанные ниже. С чем это может быть связано?

Иерархия классов такова: Skill -> PlayerSkill -> *Какой-то класс реализующий необходимую логику"

Класс Skill

```
public class Skill : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private bool CanMoveAfterCasting;
    private MoveHandler Move;
    private Mana Mana;
    [SerializeField] protected int ManaCost;
    [SerializeField] protected float MinDistanceForCastingSpell;
    [SerializeField] protected float CurrentCooldownTime;
    [SerializeField] protected float CooldownTime;
    [SerializeField] protected bool IsCooldown
    {
        get
        {
            if (CurrentCooldownTime <= 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
    protected Transform MyTransform;

    protected void Awake()
    {
        MyTransform = transform;
        Move = transform.root.GetComponent<MoveHandler>();
        Mana = transform.root.GetComponent<Mana>();
    }

    protected virtual void Use()
    {
        if (CanMoveAfterCasting == false)
            Move.Direction = Vector2.zero;
        Mana.Restore(-ManaCost);
        StartCoroutine(Cooldown());
    }

    private IEnumerator Cooldown() 
    {
        CurrentCooldownTime = CooldownTime;
        while (CurrentCooldownTime > 0)
        {
            CurrentCooldownTime -= 1f;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Класс PlayerSkill

```
public class PlayerSkill : Skill
{
    [SerializeField] protected UIDocument Document;
    protected IDeathInspector TargetHandlerInspector;
    private ParticleSystem CastingSpellEffect;
    protected Button SkillButton;
    private Label ManaCostText;
    protected string SkillButtonName;
    protected TargetHandler TargetDealer;
    protected Transform Root;

    [Inject]
    private void Construct(Document Document)
    {
        this.Document = Document.Skill;
    }

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        SkillButton.clicked += Use;
    }

    protected override void Use()
    {
        if (IsCooldown)
            return;
        if (TargetDealer.TargetTransform == null)
            return;
        float distance = (TargetDealer.TargetTransform.position - Root.position).sqrMagnitude;
        if (distance > MinDistanceForCastingSpell)
            return;

        CastingSpellEffect.Play();
        base.Use();
    }
```

Для примера один из нескольких классов наследующих PlayerSkill

```
public class Rush : PlayerSkill
{
    [SerializeField] private TrailRenderer Effect;
    [SerializeField] private float RushSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float StunDuration;
    [SerializeField] private float MinDistanceForRush;
    private Transform Target;

    protected override void Start()
    {
        SkillButtonName = "Rush";
        base.Start();
    }

    protected override void Use()
    {
        Effect.emitting = true;
        Target = TargetDealer.TargetTransform;
        Target.GetComponent<IStun>().Stun(StunDuration);
        base.Use();
    }
}
```

Comment: `в открытую игнорируются` ни о чем не говорит. Нужно видеть иерархию всех наследников, в каком из родителей что написано, про обрывкам кода мало чего понять можно.

Comment: @aepot , там всё достаточно просто, у меня иерархия строится так Skill -> PlayerSkill -> *Какой-то класс реализующий логику одного из **n** скиллов*. Skill содержит `protected virtual void Use()`, в котором просто две строки 1 - отнять ману, 2 - начать перезарядку, PlayerSkill я в топ посте написал реализацию, ну а конечный наследник просто оверрайдит и пишет base.Use() и далее прописывает какую-то логику. Конечный класс оверрайдит именно PlaySkill, тк если в VisualStudio нажать "Перейти к определению", то показывает, что переопределяется Use из PlayerSkill

Comment: У меня хреново с воображением, код покажите.

Comment: @aepot простите, не до конца понимаю, как правильно и красиво вставить код в комментарий

Comment: Код не надо вставлять в комментарий, надо вставлять в сам пост, а комментарий удалить

Comment: @aepot спасибо за подсказку. Пост исправил полной иерархией вызовов

Comment: Вы классы нормально могли показать? Я не вижу сейчас, где у вас в коде что от чего наследуется и откуда вызывается. По идее, должно работать, но я не вижу классы. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1152925/12888024

Comment: @aepot Простите за мою глупость, всё исправил

Comment: Уже лучше. Теперь осталось понять: `за исключением условий` - каких? В чем суть самой проблемы? Отлаживать пробовали? Поставить точку останова в наследнике и пройтись пошагово проверив значения всех переменных, ну либо обвешаться `Debug.Log`-ами и глядеть в консольку студии? Что из этого вы пробовали?

Comment: @aepot проверил с помощью `Debug.Log` и точек остановы, результат такой: условие с таргетом работает, как надо, а вот условие с `distance` и  `IsCooldown` ведут себя одинаково по особенному:
1) на `Debug.Log` расположенном над условием `IsCooldown` выдается верный результат, а если расположить дебаг под условием, то всегда будет `False`, даже когда брейкпоинты показывают true
2)Во время перезарядки способности точка остановы показала `IsCooldown == true` и как видно  в теле условия есть оператор return, который должен был прекратить дальнейшее выполнение тела метода, но он проигнорировался

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мог ли бы сами провести простенькую отладку расставив `Debug.Log` и посмотрев результаты.

```
protected virtual void Use()
{
    Debug.Log("Skill.Use");
    ...
}

protected override void Use()
{
    Debug.Log("PlayerSkill.Use");
    ...
    base.Use();
}

protected override void Use()
{
    Debug.Log("Rush.Use");
    ...
    base.Use();
}
```

Но вообще все очень плохо...

- `Skill` не проверяет `IsCooldown` хотя запускает корутину, но проверяет `PlayerSkill`
- `Skill` почему-то связан с `Move`, хотя это не его ответственность
- `PlayerSkill` почему-то связан с какими-то лейблы, баттоны, причем тут интерфейс?
- в `PlayerSkill` почему-то присутствуют эффекты для визуализации
- в `PlayerSkill` почему-то фигурируют трансформы кастера и цели
- почему это все MonoBehaviour?
- почему вообще существуют `Skill`, `PlayerSkill` и `Rush`? В любой rpg разработчик по желанию может дать любому, любую способность.

Информация о способности это одна история типа

```
public class AbilityInfo : ScriptableObject
{
    public Sprite Icon;
    public string Name;
    public string Discription;
    public AbilityType Type;
    public float Damage;
    public float Range;
    public float Cooldown;
    public float ManaCost;
    public float CastingDuration;
    public AbilityShell Shell;
    ...
}
```

Объект имеющий визуализацию другая история

```
public class AbilityShell : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _spawnEffect;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _hitEffect;
    private AbilityInfo _info;
    private Damage _damage;
    private Object _sorce;

    public void Execute (AbilityInfo info, Damage damage, Object sorce)
    {
        _info = info;
        _damage = damage;
        _sorce = sorce;
    }
    ...
}
```

Способность в перечне способностей исполнителя третья и ответственность у нее мало, контейнер для Info и изменчивые состояния типа статус перезарядки, уровня прокачки, число оставшихся использований. Ничего она не проверяет и ни о ком не знает. Весь пул способностей должен храниться в другом более высокоуровневом классе персонажа `UnitAbilitys`, который знает о персонаже, может проверить `CanUse (int index)` на ману, дистанцию, заспавнить где нужно согласно описанию, из руки, под ногами или на земле задав аргументы `Execute`, поставить флаг или состояние персонажа с "Move"/"Stay" на "CastingSpell", все что связано в контексте персонажа.

```
public class UnitAbility
{
    public Action Used;
    public readonly AbilityInfo Info;
    private float _reload;

    public UnitAbility (AbilityInfo info)
    {
        Info = info;
    }

    public bool IsCooldown => _reload > 0;
    public float CooldownProgress => _reload/Info.Cooldown;

    public void Use ()
    {
        _reload = Info.Cooldown;
        Used?.Invoke();
    }

    public void Update (float delta)
    {
        if (_reload > 0)
            _reload -= delta;
    }
    ...
}
```

А интерфейс соответственно тоже отдельно, скармливаешь ему `UnitAbility`, он сам заглявывает в `Info`, посмотреть на иконку, имя и описание, отриагирует на использование и отобразит перезарядку. По нажатию сам спросит `UnitAbilitys.CanUse(targetAbility)` и даст команду `UnitAbilitys.Use(targetAbility)`, либо через конструкцию `bool TryUse()`.

Comment: Боже, как же много мне еще учиться. Спасибо за столь развёрнутый ответ!